# Anaconda Nav not activating environment

Tags: terminal, anaconda, conda, environment

I have been using Navigator a couple of months now with 2 different environments plus the base. I have been able to start a terminal with out fail until today.
Now I get this error on the terminal initializing:

xterm: Can't execvp bash --init-file <(echo ". activate /home/xavier/anaconda3/envs/purple_path;"): No such file or directory

coming up with out any real direct info from searches or documentation.
anyone else run into this??
How would I resolve this issue?